# Deserialise POST paramaters in a resource

Tags: java, post, dropwizard

Coming from django background, not very strong on `dw`, please go easy!

I have a resource taking post data as below:

```
    @POST
    @Path("changestatus/{status}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response changeStatus(String dataString,
                                            @PathParam("status") Status status) {

        HashMap<String, Object> responseMessage = new HashMap<>();
        Response.Status respStatus = Response.Status.OK;
        //    --- ugly stuff to clean things hence the question!!! 
        // dataString = dataString.replace("dataString=", "").replace("%2C", ",");
        // do stuffs
```

Now, if I pass input `POST` param as `abcd,tklmj,1234cd`, the resource would have the `dataString` as `dataString=abcd%2Ctklmj%2C1234cd`.

`dataString`s value literally has `dataString` word in it, along with `,` converted to `%2C`, how do i deserialise them back to get the original input? As in remove `dataString` and `%2C` from its value.

**ajax call**

```
            var target_url = statusURL + status_text;
            data = {"dataString": all_data}
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: target_url,
                data: data,
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data)
                }
            });
```

I'm on dropwizard version 1.2.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use HashMap to handle the data from body:

```
@POST
@Path("changestatus/{status}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response changeStatus(HashMap data,
                         @PathParam("status") Status status) {
```

to get the values

```
 String param1 = (String) data.get(<your param name>)
```

Comment: updated question, added ajax call as well. M getting `Unable to process JSON` on adding `Hashmap`

Comment: on ajax, add configuration: contentType: 'application/json', and the data must be   with type json :{abc: '...', xyz: 'xyz'} , not with string as you are using

Answer (score 2):

The `Resource` is expecting JSON but you are sending form-encoded data.

You can either change the request to send valid JSON – in which case [Viet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52733940/69875) should work, or change the `Resource` to consume form-encoded data and then extract it using [`FormParam`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/FormParam.html), i.e.:

```
@POST
@Path("changestatus/{status}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED) 
public Response changeStatus(
    @FormParam("dataString") String dataString, 
    @PathParam("status") Status status) { 
    ...
}
```